# how to take phpmyadmin(mysql) backup database cron with date and time

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

How to take backup of my server database PHPMYADMIN(MYSQL) daily at 2:30 am with the zip file stored with time stamp on it.Please Help.

Comment: Why have you tagged this with 'android' and 'ios'?

Comment: Why phpmyadmin? Can't you use mysqldump?

Comment: I dont know how to do it .I am new to this.Please tell me how to achieve it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you want to make a cron you probably want to use mysqldump command.

```
mysqldump -u database_user -pdatabase-password database_name | gzip -9 > /path/to/backup/directory/database-data/$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S).sql.gz
```

Your cron will look like this:

```
30 2 * * * mysqldump -u database_user -pdatabase-password database_name | gzip -9  /path/to/backup/directory/database-data/$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S).sql.gz
```

In some systems like RHEL you might need to escape the characters from the date expression.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8584/using-the-system-date-time-in-a-cron-script

add a \ before each %. (\%Y-\%m-\%d-\%H.\%M.\%S)

Comment: what does gzip -9 stand for?

Comment: And do I have to create mysqldump or its already there on server

Comment: mysqldump is a command from mysql itself. gzip -9 is the compress method. The -9 parameter is your compression level. Check here. http://lowfatlinux.com/linux-gzip-gunzip.html you might want to use -6.it depends if you want a smaller file and a slower backup or vice-versa.

Comment: If you have some control panel like cpanel in your server you can create the cron job from there. If not you have to use command-line. Here is a nice tutorial about cron jobs http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs/

Comment: Thanks.So all I need to do is go to cron jobs ,create a cron job and choose daily 2:30 time and insert the above command in command field ?   or just insert the above command in command field ?

Comment: no,in cpanel you need to choose daily 2:30 and them in command field put the first line of code I put.

Comment: I have added this code :mysqldump -u database_user -p database-password database_name | gzip -9 > /public_html/myfolder/database_backup/database-data/$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S).sql.gz evry 15 mins I get this error via email 15 * * * * mysqldump -u database_user -p database-password database_name | gzip -9 public_html/myfolder/database_backup/database-data/$(date +            
>
bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: you need to replace the variables. database_user, database_password,database_name and the path to save the file by your real settings in the code. If you still get the error try replace the path to the file to this: /path_to_folder/filename_`date "+\%d-\%m-\%Y_\%H_\%M"`.sql.gz

Comment: Please Help.
mysqldump -u test -p test test_database > /public_html/data/database_backup/database.sql
/bin/sh: /public_html/data/database_backup/database.sql: No such file or directory


But I have created a folder public_html/data/database_backup

Comment: I tried your way:::: mysqldump -u test -p test test_database | gzip -9 > /public_html/data/database_backup/filename_`date "+%d-%m-%Y_%H_%M"`.sql.gz

/bin/sh: /public_html/data/database_backup/filename_`date "+%d-%m-%Y_%H_%M"`.sql.gz: No such file or directory
Enter password: mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' (using password: NO) when trying to connect

Comment: Do I need to add localhost anywhere ? because in php it needs localhost to connect.

Comment: there was a mistake in the code. you need to remove the space between -p and the password. Here is a working example that is working on my pc mysqldump -u root -proot test_db | gzip -9 > /var/www/$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S).sql.gz where root is my username and password

Comment: Enter password: mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'test_db'@'localhost' (using password: NO) when trying to connect    >   I am getting this error after I tried your new code

Comment: tell me your database user, password,database name and the path no the folder where do you want to save the folder and I will write the command with your data.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Home directory:/home/datadirectory
dbuser :  *****_admin
dbpassword : admin
database name :  databaseMain   (It shows as datadirectory_databaseMain)

path:    public_html/data/database_backup/database.sql
complete Path :     /home/datadirectory/public_html/data/database_backup/database.sql

Comment: Ok. Your command should be like this: mysqldump -u *****_admin  -padmin  datadirectory_databaseMain) | gzip -9 > /home/datadirectory/public_html/data/database_backup/$(date +\%Y-\%m-\%d-\%H.\%M.\%S).sql.gz

Comment: Thanks Bruno-P.This worked for me mysqldump -u *****_admin -padmin datadirectory_databaseMain > /home/datadirectory/public_html/data/database_backup/$(date +\%Y-\%m-\%d-\%H.\%M.\%S).sql

Comment: Thanks once again for explaining and teaching me the entire process.